# How can I collect and archive my sketches

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, wireframe, sketching, design-thinking

I need your help if you can, so how you turn brief into a rough sketches for app & web design (need examples plz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting project brief I'am looking for inspiration about project through some inspiration sources ([Uplabs](https://uplabs.io/), [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com), [Niice](https://niice.co) or [Pinterest](https://pinterest.com)). If I found some interesting ideas, I save these in board on my Pinterest account.

Then I draw some sketches based on these collected ideas on paper with pencil. Later I designing interfaces based on these sketches and it goes like this way...